# SQL SERVER 2000 JDBC DRIVER

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to find the SQL SERVER 2000 JDBC Driver to use in extracting data from SQL SERVER and also carrying out several operation implemented in Java/JSF. Any idea where I could get my hands on the driver? It is no surprise that Microsoft.com /MSDN stopped supporting and hence supplying the necessary driver. Please help and it is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `jTDS JDBC Driver`, it is open source and written in java and support both `Sql Server` and `Sybase`.
It says:

> jTDS is an open source 100% pure Java (type 4) JDBC 3.0 driver for
>   Microsoft SQL Server (6.5, 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008) and Sybase (10, 11,
>   12, 15). jTDS is based on FreeTDS and is currently the fastest
>   production-ready JDBC driver for SQL Server and Sybase. jTDS is 100%
>   JDBC 3.0 compatible, supporting forward-only and scrollable/updateable
>   ResultSets, concurrent (completely independent) Statements and
>   implementing all the DatabaseMetaData and ResultSetMetaData methods.
>   Check out the feature matrix for more details.
>
> Quite a few of the commercial JDBC drivers out there are based on jTDS
>   (or FreeTDS), even if they no longer acknowledge this. jTDS has been
>   tested with virtually all JDBC-based database management tools and is
>   the driver of choice for most of these (recommended for DbVisualizer
>   and SQuirreL SQL, distributed with Aqua Data Studio and DataDino).
>   jTDS is also becoming a common choice for enterprise-level
>   applications: it passes both the J2EE 1.3 certification and Hibernate
>   test suites, and is recommended for JBoss, Hibernate, Atlassian JIRA
>   and Confluence and Compiere.

you can download and read more information of it in http://jtds.sourceforge.net/.